# fishpig magento integration comment to blog not showing name

Tags: php, magento

I am new to **magento**. I have installed **fishpig** in my magento site. When I logged in to my magento site and select any blog to post comment, I am not able to see the **text-box** for name and email, and when I submit the post it wont show me name by whom the comment is posted.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry for the language but let me know if I am missing anything...

Comment: Solved the problem by retrieving logged in user's name and email address from magento's class and kept it in hidden field so that when you post comment hidden field's value will get posted....